# Ace linters - All annotations are of type error

Tags: python, angular, ace-editor

I m using ace-linters for ace editor to perform linting for languages like python, sql, json etc

The linting works pretty good with the help of web workers.
It returns the proper annotations.
But all the annotations are marked as error type even if some of them, according to me, should be warning annotations. Please refer below example

Is there a way to fix this issue? by either controlling the error codes or just the annotations as they are returned

```
[
    {
        "row": 0,
        "column": 7,
        "text": "F401 `pandas` imported but unused",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 2,
        "column": 18,
        "text": "F401 `pandas` imported but unused",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 2,
        "column": 44,
        "text": "F401 `numpy` imported but unused",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 3,
        "column": 88,
        "text": "E501 Line too long (136 > 88 characters)",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 6,
        "column": 88,
        "text": "E501 Line too long (112 > 88 characters)",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 8,
        "column": 88,
        "text": "E501 Line too long (93 > 88 characters)",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 10,
        "column": 88,
        "text": "E501 Line too long (173 > 88 characters)",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 12,
        "column": 88,
        "text": "E501 Line too long (90 > 88 characters)",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 14,
        "column": 88,
        "text": "E501 Line too long (101 > 88 characters)",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "row": 18,
        "column": 88,
        "text": "E501 Line too long (128 > 88 characters)",
        "type": "error"
    }
]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the list of rules you want to ignore by providing their prefixes to the `ignore` property of `configuration`:

```js
languageProvider.setGlobalOptions("python", {
    configuration: {
        "ignore": ["E501", "F401"]
    }
});
```

Comment: Top!. thanks. I m looking for the config where the error codes can be set as warning instead of error

Comment: With new version (0.10.0) you could set which errors you want to ignore or replace as warnings/info -
For Python Service it would be -
`languageProvider.setGlobalOptions("python", {errorCodesToTreatAsWarning: ["E501","F401"]});`

Comment: errorCodesToTreatAsWarning didn't seem to work. it is still returning errors. also tried it inside the configuration property.
https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff/blob/main/ruff.schema.json
its not given in this page also

Comment: It should work; look to python example [here](https://mkslanc.github.io/ace-linters/default_services.html) and it's code [here](https://github.com/mkslanc/ace-linters/blob/main/packages/demo/webworker-lsp/demo.ts#L136) . Blind guess - maybe you haven't updated package to version 0.10.0 or it could be caching problem.

Comment: Thanks Azat. It was the version which was conflicting. works well now.